# space of robin boundary condition

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $K$ be a subset defined as
$$
K=\{u\in H^1(\Omega)|\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}+u=0\ \text{on }\partial\Omega\}
$$
Is the subspace $K$ closed in $H^1(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define $\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}$ on $\partial\Omega$ for $u \in H^1(\Omega)$. You need more regularity of $u$, e.g., $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$ for the definition of the normal derivative.

Comment: Pedantic note: If for $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ you require $\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}+u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$, it follows that $u\in H^2(\Omega)$. So it seems that the OP needs to assume (at least) $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ in order for $K$ to be well-defined.

Comment: @StarBug: This is only true if the boundary of $\Omega$ is smooth enough. If $\Omega$ is, e.g., the L-shape, $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$ (plus b.c.) does not give $u \in H^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: I see. But what if I require u in $H^2$, is the K a closed subset of $H^2$?

Comment: Yes, of course. This follows from the fact that $H^2 \ni u \mapsto du/dv + u \in L^2(\partial\Omega)$ is continuous (under the assumption of some regularity of $\partial\Omega$).

Comment: @gerw But it seems that the example given by daw is also a counterexample if $u\in H^2$. I cannot see why this happened.

Comment: No, these functions are not in  $H^2$.

Comment: @gerw Oh, I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take $\Omega=(0,1)$. Let $\epsilon\in (0,1/4)$. Define
$$
u_\epsilon(x) = \begin{cases}
1+x & \text{ if } x\in (0,\epsilon)\\
1+2\epsilon- x & \text{ if } x\in (\epsilon,2\epsilon)\\
1 &  \text{ if } x\in (2\epsilon,1-2\epsilon)\\
1+(x-(1-2\epsilon)) &  \text{ if } x\in (1-2\epsilon,1-\epsilon)\\
2-x &  \text{ if } x\in (1-\epsilon,1),
\end{cases}
$$
so $u_\epsilon$ is constant one except for two hat-shaped perturbations of height $\epsilon$ and width $2\epsilon$. Clearly, $u_\epsilon\in H^1(0,1)$. Moreover, $u_\epsilon$ is continuously differentiable near the boundary of $\Omega$. And $u_\epsilon \in K$.

In addition $u_\epsilon \to 1$ in $H^1(0,1)$: $\|u_\epsilon-1\|_{L^\infty(0,1)}\le \epsilon$, $\|\nabla u_\epsilon\|_{L^\infty(0,1)}=1$, and measure of support of $u_\epsilon-1$ is equal to $4\epsilon$. But $1\not \in K$.

Comment: So, from your example, even if we require u in $H^2$, K is not the closed set in $H^2$, right?

Comment: This would be a different question with a different answer.